# Computer algebra system to simplify huge rational functions (of order 100 Mbytes)

Tags: symbolic-computation

I have a huge rational function of three variables (which is of order ~100Mbytes if dumped to a text file) which I believe to be identically zero.  Unfortunately, neither Mathematica nor Maple succeeded in simplifying the expression to zero.

I substituted a random set of three integers to the rational function and indeed it evaluated to zero; but just for curiosity, I would like to  use a computer algebra system to simplify it. Which computer algebra system should I use? I've heard of Magma, Macaulay2, singular, GAP, sage to list a few. Which is best suited to simplify a huge rational expression?

---

In case you want to try simplifying the expressions yourself, I dumped available in two notations, [Mathematica notation](http://member.ipmu.jp/yuji.tachikawa/tmp/big.mathematica.zip) and [Maple notation](http://member.ipmu.jp/yuji.tachikawa/tmp/big.maple.zip). Unzip the file and do

```
<<"big.mathematica"
```

or

```
read("big.maple")
```

from the interactive shell. This loads expressions called `gauge` and `cft`, both rational functions of `a1`, `a2` and `b`. Each of which is non-zero, but I believe `gauge=cft`. So you should be able to simplify `gauge-cft` to zero. The relation comes from a string duality, see e.g. [this paper by M. Taki](http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.4789).

Comment: Wow, a 100Mbyte expression! Where did it come from?

Comment: Would you mind expanding on this "string duality" you speak of? I am now quite curious...

Comment: This is the 3rd term of a conjectured equality; the 1st and the 2nd terms are explained in a published paper http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.4789 by M. Taki

Comment: If Mathematica and Maple can't simplify it, I would be inclined to believe that it can't be simplified. Rational functions have a canonical representation which is fairly easy to reduce to.

Comment: Well, but the expression is identically zero (as you can check by yourself by putting numerical values). The problem, I believe, is the amount of memory Mathematica or Maple needs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Mathematica* can actually prove that `gauge-cft` is exactly zero.

To carry out the proof observe that expression for `gauge` is much smaller than the `cft`. Hence we first canonicalize `gauge` using `Together`, and then multiply `cft` by it denominator:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry for my confusing explanation... what's supposed to be zero is `gauge-cft`.

Comment: @Yuji Please see my updated answer. Computations of `Cancel[Denominator[g2]*cft]` took about 40 minutes.

Comment: Wow, you're a super expert on Mathematica! ... and I learned you're in fact the kernel developer. I'm honored to meet you. Please implement this trick to `FullSimplify` :)

Answer (score 9):

For highly recursive rational expressions it is better to factor.  Here is a Maple program that does it in 3 minutes on a Core i7 2600, suggested by Mike Monagan:

```
rec := proc(a) option remember;
  if type(a,{`*`,`+`}) then
    factor(map(rec, a));
  elif type(a,`^`) then
    rec(op(1,a))^op(2,a);
  else a;
  end if;
end proc:

read "big.maple":
CodeTools:-Usage(rec(gauge - cft));  # returns zero
memory used=24.06GiB, alloc change=276.79MiB, cpu time=3.53m, real time=3.00m
```

Comment: Thank you for the new info!